# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) when using aiomangadexapi

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

What I'm working on is something to access MangaDex and check for new chapters, using an albeit old and as far as I can tell decrepit API, however it is the only API I have found for Python. In short, what I believe should be happening is the code uses json.loads() to turn a string gotten from a link, into a dict and then access the keys/values of that dict. However, something is clearly wrong with the string it should be converting.

Traceback starting from relevant code:

```
    newLink = await getLink(mangaName, newChapterNum)
  File "/home/eisbar/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/main.py", line 45, in getLink
    link = await mdapi.get_chapter(session, manga, chapter)
  File "/home/eisbar/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiomangadexapi/__init__.py", line 170, in get_chapter
    data = await search(session,name)
  File "/home/eisbar/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiomangadexapi/__init__.py", line 129, in search
    data = parse(response)
  File "/home/eisbar/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiomangadexapi/__init__.py", line 78, in parse
    payload = json.loads(response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I do understand from the traceback that s to be converted is in some way malformed in the first character. However, here is the string that should be converted, with the links removed:

`{"code":200,"status":"OK","data":{"manga":{"id":48959,"title":"Ardor's Kingdom","altTitles":["\uc544\ub354\uc758 \uc655\uad6d"],"description":"An exiled prince's hectic school life in his quest to become the next King Ardor!","artist":["Yoonsoo"],"author":["Yoonsoo"],"publication":{"language":"kr","status":2,"demographic":1},"tags":[5,10,13,36,47],"lastChapter":null,"lastVolume":null,"isHentai":false,"links":{"ap":"ardors-kingdom","mu":"178415","raw":"XXXXXXXX"},"chapters":[{"id":896342,"hash":"db877e42e29ecf94c610d672c5602c19","mangaId":48959,"mangaTitle":"Ardor's Kingdom","volume":"","chapter":"1","title":"","language":"gb","groups":[657],"uploader":1166686,"timestamp":1589822996,"threadId":251978,"comments":4,"views":889}],"groups":[{"id":657,"name":"no group"}]}}`

The only explanation I could think of after going through this is that the string above is in some way not passed through the json.loads() chain properly, although I have no clue as to why or how that would happen, or how to test or fix it. As a final note, in case it would help someone if they can touch the source code themselves, the module is `aiomangadexapi.py`.

**Edit0: I'll try my best to add a reprex, but first time doing one that crosses multiple files and into source.**
Code written by me that requests the link and begins the chain:

```
async def getLink(manga, chapter):
    session = await aiomangadexapi.login('username', 'password')
    link = await aiomangadexapi.get_chapter(session, mangaName, chapterNumber) #Point at which traceback errors

    await session.close()
    return link
```

Between these is a two-line function that passes `mangaName` from above to the `search` function below

```
async def search(session,name,link=False):

    if not link:
        name = name.replace(" ", "%20")
        name = name.replace("[", "%5B")
        name = name.replace("[", "%5D")
        name = name.replace("?", "%3F")

        response = await fetch(session, 'https://mangadex.org/search?tag_mode_exc=any&tag_mode_inc=all&title={}'.format(name))
        link = fetch_link(response)
    else:
        link = 'https://mangadex.org/' + "api/v2/manga/" + name.split("title/")[1].split('/',1)[0] + "?include=chapters"

        response = await fetch(session, link)     #this line previously in source was not indented, however it caused a separate error that was fixed when indented.
    data = parse(response) #Point at which Traceback errors

    return data
```

The final code before it enters built-in python JSON files, going through loads - decode - raw_decode in the traceback.

```
def parse(response):

    GENRES = {
        #Removed here because not necessary and/or certain parts against SO rules
    }

    payload = json.loads(response) #Point at which traceback errors.
    data, chapters = payload['data']['manga'], payload['data']['chapters'] 

    #More code relating to the data variable below this, however removed as it is not executed due to code erroring on payload definition.


    return [data]
```

Comment: The error message indicates that what you received isn't JSON at all, probably an empty string. You really do need to provide a [mre]; perhaps doctor the traceback slightly to remove the links if there are too many.